# Upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10, network settings for wireless disappeared

Tags: networking, wireless, 23.10

I upgraded my Laptop from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and everything seems to work fine except I lost the setting for my wireless interface.  When I go to settings there's no settings for wireless anymore.  I know my card and drivers are working as I can go into the command line and setup the wireless connection using wpa_supplicant and dhclient, but I'd much rather have the settings and scan again in the GUI.  Anyone else experience this?  Any help would be Appriciated.

Output of "ls /etc/netplan" is blank.  Theres nothing in the directory.  I've also added a screenshot of my settings page. Where network is on 23.04 there used to also be a wireless settings which is now gone.

[Screenshot of missing wireless setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5IFN.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls /etc/netplan/` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue this is the output of running the `ls /etc/netplan` command on @chili555's comment I noticed that a new netplan file would be created whenever I tried to connect with a saved wifi network. So I only kept the `00-installer-config-wifi.yaml` and `00-installer-config.yaml`  and removed other files.

```
00-installer-config-wifi.yaml                    90-NM-3c9c4892-2be4-40ae-b30c-5dfd07827697.yaml  90-NM-9ead26c9-a8a5-4fd2-a92a-58d3a6e902fd.yaml
00-installer-config.yaml                         90-NM-40815830-2383-4547-9c95-780877ec7504.yaml  90-NM-adc66245-37b2-4b74-b922-ae51239deb23.yaml
90-NM-0261014b-2885-4d21-989d-9141c3c1ff4a.yaml  90-NM-4f0669ec-7701-40c2-8a18-9edf58682d7a.yaml  90-NM-b530a595-06c5-442e-bbb1-54e1440e8fb5.yaml
90-NM-06bf672a-2a15-49b0-ba40-4b1606f4066f.yaml  90-NM-5d5fb44b-4bfe-4c3c-a838-b6f4140b847a.yaml  90-NM-bb2266c1-c4c5-48af-ba6a-ea6aa33893f3.yaml
90-NM-0adfb540-3b53-45af-aca1-69993620b172.yaml  90-NM-601a99df-452c-4306-9202-4445890ae945.yaml  90-NM-bcea5f7a-95bf-4b13-9e29-fa61cfc42394.yaml
90-NM-0f499a05-6606-4620-b902-a59f53011e2c.yaml  90-NM-612ed533-2425-4043-9dfe-050850c3b6b2.yaml  90-NM-c4d0e7c3-869b-47b9-8267-851611a7dbf9.yaml
90-NM-11292a4f-6748-4510-9327-d0bbd0d7ec9f.yaml  90-NM-6c776b06-6cbf-453a-bd4c-c476691f21d5.yaml  90-NM-cd5a3ba2-74e0-48b9-918f-c3a170c7aebd.yaml
90-NM-16f6735d-62ed-4125-b975-af8f708296b8.yaml  90-NM-755c76e5-27fc-4df4-a1e7-3ccaff03fb59.yaml  90-NM-d7592e17-08c5-420d-ac3f-a6c295aed8f9.yaml
90-NM-18c2cb7a-28bb-4a80-8982-351f98b19a30.yaml  90-NM-7db8f119-b6cc-4655-9a79-91116d498a8e.yaml  90-NM-dbf9ec28-7e71-47d3-8bcf-32965cfed90e.yaml
90-NM-2673a838-fab2-4a58-84de-03e1f77f421a.yaml  90-NM-7e3e6d3a-636f-4f59-9280-28b9fde32b49.yaml  90-NM-e2233a15-2f86-41da-b858-26e4a2ae91b6.yaml
90-NM-2f58c796-ad77-440e-acdc-33dc3edc851b.yaml  90-NM-7e7320f4-ef4c-4679-8f7a-c72337992ef4.yaml  90-NM-ea44858e-771e-420d-8e2f-b7e923f2891b.yaml
90-NM-33a5a934-5831-462d-8e58-12e5c8cfa8aa.yaml  90-NM-820eacb0-b647-489d-ad43-5b08c5b851cb.yaml  90-NM-ecf92f1f-fa7b-43f9-ba4e-deba3e86c322.yaml
90-NM-354bb974-7d35-4200-8e76-76196375cf74.yaml  90-NM-8577f201-8ea4-4f20-a188-9009fd6ed763.yaml  90-NM-f224b55e-7dd2-4e13-9467-3afbe3fdb5fd.yaml
90-NM-35ff356b-89f9-4c86-b9b1-157e5a79db13.yaml  90-NM-885a9fc6-d0ed-419c-bd8f-4886a72810b8.yaml  90-NM-ffd4dc29-f781-44a4-bd02-f66283271dca.yaml
```

After removing the files I tried connecting to my home network and it is able to connect.

This is my first time answering please forgive me if it isn't concise enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is easy to follow what you did.  I think my issue is slightly different as I'm not even able to see or select my network from within the GUI.  The wireless option under settings is just missing.  I've included a screenshot of the settings page with the original post